# Is there such a thing as RESTful URLs

Tags: rest, url

I'm new to REST. I think I'm understanding most of it. However, whether a particular style of URL has anything to do with REST is still confusing. Part of what I read on the web talks about the URL style and in other sources I have seen it argued that the URL style has absolutely nothing to do with REST. So what's the correct answer? And if the answer is that the URL style has nothing to do with it, then why do so many frameworks that "support" REST enforce (or at least support) one style of URL? I would just like to put this issue to rest (bad pun intended).

Comment: Who is saying that URL style doesn't matter and why? As it is, your question is too vague. Off the top of my head, using clean URLs have at least two benefits: 1) user/dev friendly 2) easily cachable

Comment: OK, I think I asked the question incorrectly. Let me try again. There are many tutorials on REST out there. Many of them talk about "RESTful" URLs. Here is an example from one of the sites:

GET|PUT|DELETE http://www.example.com/products/66432
for reading, updating, deleting product 66432, respectively.

But you will see comments that this is a style preference, but isn't really part of REST. So I guess my real question is: Is there such a thing as a "RESTful URL" or is the URL a design choice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that there is no strict rules that require some fixed URL style. And you can use diferrent styles. But will be better if you use characters of lower case with meaningful words that will at least give some ideas about operation that it performs.